# Why this os loop doesn't print out the full paths of all of the files and just gives some of them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, operating-system, filepath

I've written this to find the paths of all the .aseprite files:

```
import os
x = 0
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir("c:/Users/Buğra/")
for docs, subs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".aseprite"):
            x += 1
            print(x, f, "===", os.path.dirname(docs))
```

Although it gives all the path of most of them, it doesn't print out the full path of the ones in the Downloads folder.

```
c:\Users\Bu�ra\Desktop\Kodlama
34 wixard.aseprite === c:\Users\Bu�ra\Desktop\Kodlama
35 boduragac.aseprite === c:\Users\Bu�ra
36 flower.aseprite === c:\Users\Bu�ra
37 painti1.aseprite === c:\Users\Bu�ra
38 painti10.aseprite === c:\Users\Bu�ra
39 painti19.aseprite === c:\Users\Bu�ra
40 painti2.aseprite === c:\Users\Bu�ra
41 painti3.aseprite === c:\Users\Bu�ra
42 painti4.aseprite === c:\Users\Bu�ra
43 painti5.aseprite === c:\Users\Bu�ra
44 painti6.aseprite === c:\Users\Bu�ra
45 painti7.aseprite === c:\Users\Bu�ra
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Because they are 2 different paths (one is a sub-directory of the other). [`oswalk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) searches the whole tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this?

````py
import os
x = 0
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir("<your dir/path>")
for docs, subs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".aseprite"):
            x += 1
            print(x, f, "===", docs)```
````

Answer (score 1):

use
`print(x, f, "===", docs)`

instead of
`print(x, f, "===", os.path.dirname(docs))`